# How to return the same instance every time when resolving object with Swinject?

Tags: ios, swift, swinject

Currrently I do:

```
    container.register(TabBarViewModelable.self) { (_, tabBarItems: [TabBarItemType]) in
        return TabBarViewModel(tabBarItems: tabBarItems)
    }.inObjectScope(.container)
```

and it doesn't work. Is there a way to return the same instance every time after I initialized it first time with array of tab bar items?

Comment: you can make TabBarViewModel singleton and return it

Answer (score -2):

You can use the **singleton** pattern.

Basically, you can wrap TabBarViewModel within another singleton class and return the object of that class.

Have a look at

https://medium.com/@nimjea/singleton-class-in-swift-17eef2d01d88

Comment: very very bad idea;)